# How to get lists of 'id' field after insert in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using this code to create dynamically row in Gridview and I'm using LINQ to insert those rows to DB. Now i want to return lists of ID after insert into DB but i don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
#region [Get List Visitors]
private void GetListVisitors() {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox visitor_txtName = (TextBox)grdListVisitors.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
                    TextBox visitor_txtAdd = (TextBox)grdListVisitors.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtAdd");
                    //ASPxComboBox visitor_cbxSex = (ASPxComboBox)grdListVisitors.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("cbxSex");

                    sc.Add(visitor_txtName.Text + "," + visitor_txtAdd.Text);
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                //Store the current data to StringCollection
                AddListVisitors(sc);
            }
}
#endregion

#region [Add List Visitors]
private void AddListVisitors(StringCollection sc)
{
    try {
        List_Visitor add_visitors = new List_Visitor();
        string[] splitItems = null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                Travel_DBDataContext db = new Travel_DBDataContext();
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                add_visitors.Fullname = splitItems[0];
                add_visitors.add = splitItems[1];
                db.List_Visitors.InsertOnSubmit(add_visitors);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }

        }      
    }
    catch (Exception addvisitors_error) {
        Response.Write(addvisitors_error.Message + "_method addlistvisitor");
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Why are you submitting changes on every loop iteration?

Comment: @recursive i add each row in DB

Comment: The InsertOnSubmit prepares the context to add the items, you should only call SubmitChanges at the end, then all inserts will be executed against the DB in a single call. Far more efficient and faster than making a DB call for each row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get primary key value when i insert a new record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788320/how-can-i-get-primary-key-value-when-i-insert-a-new-record)

Comment: @RichardSeal if i put SubmitChanges at the end. Only last row added

Comment: Thats because you are not creating a new List_Visitor object for each insert, you are using the same one. I'll add an answer with some changes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `SubmitChanges` has been called, the `add_visitors` object will contain the primary key of the newly inserted row.

To get all the ids a bit of refactoring is suggested:

```
// First build an in memory list of objects to add.
var listsToAdd = new List<List_Visitor>();
foreach (string item in sc)
{
  if (item.Contains(","))
  {
    var splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());

    listsToAdd.Add(new List_Visitor()
    {
      Fullname = splitItems[0],
      add = splitItems[1]
    });
  }
}

// Then add all to the db in one call. Wrap in using block to
// propery dispose of the DataContext and underlying connection.
using(var db = new Travel_DBDataContext())
{
  db.List_Visitors.InsertAllOnSubmit(listsToAdd);
  db.SubmitChanges();
}

// At this point listsToAdd contains all added lists with the generated
// primary key.
```

Comment: i know it...But in my code, i add row dynamically. How can i get lists of id after insert. Not just one id. Hope you help me :)

Comment: Refactor the code to keep the objects even after they are submitted, see my edit.

Comment: thank you so much. Your code work very well. If i use lists of id in listsToAdd for other method. What should I do?

Comment: That's another question, so post it as a separate one. Don't forget to include relevant code for that scenario in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

As Anders Abel said, once you have called SubmitChanges, the Id will be updated in the objects that have been inserted, but you need to keep a reference to those objects, right now you are using a single object which wont work.

```
#region [Add List Visitors]
private void AddListVisitors(StringCollection sc)
{
    try {
        var newVisitors = new List<List_Visitor>();
        string[] splitItems = null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                Travel_DBDataContext db = new Travel_DBDataContext();
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                var add_visitors = new List_Visitor();
                add_visitors.Fullname = splitItems[0];
                add_visitors.add = splitItems[1];
                db.List_Visitors.InsertOnSubmit(add_visitors);

                newVisitors.Add(add_visitors);
            }
        }    
        db.SubmitChanges();
        // Now newVisitors will contain a collection of List_Visitor
        // objects with the new Id's in.  
    }
    catch (Exception addvisitors_error) {
        Response.Write(addvisitors_error.Message + "_method addlistvisitor");
    }
}
#endregion
```