# LINQ-to-SQL get Primary Key from Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having some troubles figuring out why I receive a `NullReferenceException` when using this code:

```
entityCustomer customer = new entityCustomer { 
                              firstName = txtFName.Text, 
                              lastName = txtLName.Text, 
                              homeAddress = txtAddress.Text, 
                              phoneNumb = txtPhone.Text, 
                              emailAddress = txtEmail.Text 
                          };

custTable.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

I get the error on `InsertOnSubmit`. Here is my entity class:

http://pastebin.com/49RtamPN

I tried following https://stackoverflow.com/a/788402/2416047, as you can see, but still had no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note - we use PascalCase for properties and class names

Comment: is custTable instantiated?  You may need to supply more code than that to let us debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `custTable` variable, parameter, property or field is null.
You need to assign a value to it before calling any of its members.

Comment: And this I where I realize I missed instantiating custTable. Thanks!