# Return an Object from Database.SqlQuery

Tags: linq, object

There's a way with `Database.SqlQuery` to return the new object created ?

With Linq I do it this way :

```
Category category
db.Categories.Add(category);
db.SaveChanges();
return category;
```

Now category is an object that return the new category created with the new id.

How to do it with `SqlQuery`?

```
 return db.Database.SqlQuery<Category>("INSERT INTO " + categoryTable + " (title,description) VALUES ({0},{1}) ", category.title, category.description);
```

It returns a empty array but i want to return the new category created with the new id.

Thank you.

Comment: You could also just put: `db.Database.Log=Debug.WriteLine;` before you did your LINQ, and see what it generates.

Comment: Why use SqlQuery? It should be possible with Linq. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788320/how-can-i-get-primary-key-value-when-i-insert-a-new-record

Comment: Because i didnt find a way with LINQ to use a dynamic table. ex : categoryTable. And i want to avoid the use of conditions like : if, case, etc

Comment: Lol, you are probably the same guy who asked the other questions.  You can also do (from my previous answers): `db.GetTable("yourtable").Add(category); db.SubmitChanges():`

Comment: Lol, hey i opened a chat room with you !  By the way i will always need to use the conditions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need this because `Category` has an autonumber `Id` property of some kind. Haven't tested this myself, but maybe you can get that to work by using the [output clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) of the insert statement. e.g.

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<Category>("INSERT INTO " + categoryTable + " (title,description) OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.title, inserted.description VALUES ({0},{1}) ", category.title, category.description);
```